# Boostrap's column's padding constrain in css

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

demo here http://www.bootply.com/stuqpDhmWp

As you can see in above demo, my img is 100% but the padding between the img is too big because left and right total is 30px. I wish it could be like the side which is 15px only. Any hack on that?

Answer (score 0):

```
.container .col-md-3{ padding:0px 7.5px}

.container .col-md-3:first-child {padding-left:15px;}
.container .col-md-3:last-child {padding-right:15px;}
```

it will fix your problem

Comment: how ever this will effect the entire grid system on your website.. i will suggest adding a custom class somewhere with container.

Comment: but you dont have to use container-compact if it is not necessary

Comment: nice try but still abit bug there, look at the first and last img's height.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

To avoid padding use `row` in particular `col`

## [DEMO](http://www.bootply.com/s5TzdGSg7X)

```
<div class="container">

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3">
            <img src="http://i.imgur.com/NRAVLP1.png">
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 row">
            <img src="http://i.imgur.com/NRAVLP1.png">
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 ">
            <img src="http://i.imgur.com/NRAVLP1.png">
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 row">
            <img src="http://i.imgur.com/NRAVLP1.png">
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="container">                         

    <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-padding">
                    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/NRAVLP1.png">
            </div>

            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-padding">
                    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/NRAVLP1.png">
            </div>

            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-padding">
                    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/NRAVLP1.png">
            </div >
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-padding">
                    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/NRAVLP1.png">
            </div>

        </div>  
    </div>
```

css:

```
.col-padding{padding-right: 0}
.col-padding:last-child{padding-right: 15px}
```

Comment: Can you show me the result? Do you need it for one row of your site or just one row. If you need this style for all row then you can customize your bootstrap from http://getbootstrap.com/customize/